# How to use StreamingHttpResponse to send content in chunks in a Django project?

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I use Django for local development, and use StreamingHttpResponse to send content in chunks. However, when deploying with Django+uwsgi+nginx, the StreamingHttpResponse no longer sends content in chunks, only sending it all at once. What could be causing this?

this is my uwsgi config

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:8082
chdir = /usr/release/publicapi/
wsgi-file = publicapi/wsgi.py
module = publicapi.wsgi
master = true
#home = /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/bg/
daemonize = /usr/release/logs/uwsgi.log
vacuum = true
processes = 5
pidfile = /usr/local/nginx/uwsgi/uwsgi8086.pid
home = /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/bg/
#ignore-sigpipe=true
#ignore-write-errors=true
#disable-write-exception=true
harakiri=3000
post-buffering=56553600
http-timeout=6000
```